# xcode parse or read html content loaded into webview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, jquery-mobile

I am loading a jqueryMobile html page into a webview. Is there any method to read a parameter set on html file in order to then execute native functions? how and where to set it? any help would be appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let javascript do the work for you.

1. Include a javascript function which returns the value as string. say `getParam()`
2. When are finished with loading the HTML, use the  `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` method of UIWebView (upon `webViewDidFinishLoad`)

Eg:

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSString *param = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"getParam();"];
}
```